# meaning of 'cop'

Tags: word-meaning

> I’ll **cop** to using a cliché, but treasure trove is hardly redundant.
>   Trove has accrued its modern meaning of ‘‘a valuable collection’’ only
>   because it has hung around treasure for so long.

[Treasure Trove](http://www.nytimes.com/2011/01/09/magazine/09FOB-onlanguage-t.html)

What is the meaning of **cop** here? I looked up the dictionary, but it doesn't help.
Thank you.

Comment: Look up *cop to* in [Macmillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/cop-to): "to admit to something embarrassing or something you have done wrong"

Comment: I vote to leave this open - my go-to dictionaries (Collins / Merriam Webster) don't list "cop to". So while this is *technically* answerable with the right dictionary, it's not easily done so.

Comment: @Stephie "slang :  admit 2b —used with to <these small-timers would…cop to the smallest offense their attorney could negotiate — Tom Clancy>" -- [Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cop).

Comment: I saw that one too - but this is just a tiny entry and as a learner I wouldn't have recognized this, or at least not trusted my judgement enough, especially if other dictionaries don't list it. I still think the question should be admissible here because it's a rather rare / slangy use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full OED has 12 completely separate entries for ***cop*** (8 nouns, and 4 verbs). The sense of OP's cited usage derives from these definitions within the ***Verb 3*** entry...

> **1 to cop** verb, dialect/slang - *to capture, catch, lay hold of, ‘nab’*

...leading to the phrasal verb...

> **2 to cop it** - *to ‘catch’ it, to be punished, get into trouble*

...and thence to...

> **3 to cop a plea**
>    a: *to plead guilty, usu. as part of a bargain or agreement with the prosecution*
>    b: *(U.S. Black English slang) to avoid telling the truth, be evasive.*

Although not explicitly noted by OED, **3a** is increasingly used without ***a plea***. It's important to note that the underlying "courtroom bargaining" sense there implies *plead guilty **to a lesser offence*** (than the one you're *really* guilty of, but which the prosecution don't think they can prove).

Note the Macmillan definition in @snailboat's comment: [*to admit to something **embarrassing***](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/cop-to). It's usually a somewhat facetious usage, in that the speaker (more often, *writer* - a columnist, blogger, etc. wishing to inject an informal/lighthearted tone into his text) doesn't usually think he's admitting to anything that's actually *wrong*. It's more likely he's gently poking fun at those who might criticize his action (and implicitly inviting his readers to share his perspective), so it's actually more a form of "inverted boasting" - *some* people might disapprove, but not the writer (or sympathetic readers).

Given that sense **3b** above is almost the "opposite" of **3a** (superficially, at least), I would advise caution in using it. Outside of the courtroom context, sense **2** is far more common, and I suspect most people would understand OP's cited usage as being facetiously based on that (implying that the "crime" admitted to is either trivial or not actually "wrong" at all).